# How can I Compare Json to string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hi all hope you can help. I'm using `jquery` to do an **ajax call**, I get the result from **php** using `json_encode()` which works perfectly. the returned result I want to compare to a string but for some reason this is causing me headaches. I've tried converting the value to string, I've tried using many variations to try to compare. Can someone please guide me in the right direction. Below is the "success" section of the ajax call. If I put the result in an `alert()` it shows the result on screen but I cannot compare it to a string.

```
success: function(data){
  if (data == "no")
  {
      alert("you said no");
  } else {
  alert("you said yes");
  }
},
```

Comment: what's your json structure..?

Comment: Try this: http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                            var x = obj.colname;
```

Parse the result that is data getting after success opertation in ajax and fetch appropriate col name structure of your ajax

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance. Your answer, Kedar B, works perfectly. thanks, I unfortunately can't "up" your answer, but will will select it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is **JSON.parse** to convert response to array.

```
success: function(data){
  var response = JSON.parse(data);

  if(response['test']['value'] == 0) {
     alert();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose (if it's interpreted as json ..) that inside your ajax call you have something like

```
dataType:"json"
```

Just delete this line